# How to detect whether video gets paused or not?

Tags: android

I have a question that how to check whether video get paused? means I want to call an Intent on Pausing a video so how can I detect whether Video gets paused or not?

Please help about this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you manualy implement the PauseButton action or you have set the media controller to your video view ? Please put some code of it,

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the MediaPlayer in Android, you can use IsPlaying()

Answer (score 0):

Are you playing the video using a VideoView class or an external application ?. If you have a visible button in your VideoView for pause action you can throw an intent in its setonClickListener method.